# Apply the Savitzky-Golay filter with locked endpoints

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a stream of values I would like to smooth with `locked end-points`, meaning that the first and last data elements of the array are taken into account in the filtering algorithm but remain untouched.

For the smoothing algorithm I chose `scipy.signal.savgol_filter`, which gives me good results, except that I cannot figure out how to lock the end-points even after padding the values.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

def smooth_data(data, n, polyorder):
    
    # n is the number samples on either side of the sliding window
    window_length = n * 2 + 1 # window_length is always odd
    
    # pad the end-points
    padded_data = np.zeros(data.shape[0] + 2 * n)
    padded_data[:n] = data[0]
    padded_data[-n:] = data[-1]
    padded_data[n:-n] = data
            
    filtered_data = savgol_filter(padded_data , window_length, polyorder)[n:-n]
    return filtered_data[n:-n]


source_data = np.sort(np.random.random(100))
smooth_data = smooth_data(source_data , window_size=31, polyorder=5)
print(np.allclose(source_data[0], smooth_data[0]))   # False
print(np.allclose(source_data[-1], smooth_data[-1])) # False
```

If you run this code you will see that despite padding the data, the `ends-points` are still affected.

As a temp solution I decided to linearly interpolate the filtered data so the `end-points` do match.

```
def smooth_data(data, n, polyorder):
    
    # n is the number samples on either side of the sliding window
    window_length = n * 2 + 1 # window_length is always odd
    
    # pad the end-points
    padded_data = np.zeros(data.shape[0] + 2 * n)
    padded_data[:n] = data[0]
    padded_data[-n:] = data[-1]
    padded_data[n:-n] = data
            
    filtered_data = savgol_filter(padded_data , window_length, polyorder)[n:-n]
    
    # linearly adjust the values so the endpoints match
    delta0 = data[0] - filtered_data[0]
    delta1 = data[-1] - filtered_data[-1]
    linspace = np.linspace(0, 1, data.shape[0])
    filtered_data += delta0 + (delta1 - delta0) * linspace
    
    return filtered_data


source_data = np.sort(np.random.random(100))
smooth_data = smooth_data(source_data , n=31, polyorder=5)
print(np.allclose(source_data[0], smooth_data[0]))   # True
print(np.allclose(source_data[-1], smooth_data[-1])) # True
```

This does the trick, but feels very dirty to me. Also it is debatable if there is still a need to pad the values when interpolating. Results are a bit different with or without. So far i've opted to keep the padded values.

**QUESTION**

Can `savgol_filter` be made to lock the `end-points`? And if not, are there any other filtering schemes I could use to reduce noise in my data but lock the `end-points`?

Sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the endpoints to be exactly the same values as the original data or very close is sufficient?

Comment: @jared very close might work. Suggest an answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `scipy.signal.savgol_filter` maybe consider using [`scipy.interpolate.make_smoothing_spline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.make_smoothing_spline.html). The key to ensuring the endpoints are nearly preserved is to adjust the weights of the points such that the endpoints are weighted highly compared to the interior points. But, this isn't super reliable and will depend on the data--sometimes it works well and sometimes not. I guess it's a question of how much error you're willing to accept.

See the example code below, which I've adapted from the `make_smoothing_spline` documentation example.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_smoothing_spline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

def func(x):
   return x**3 + x**2 * np.sin(4 * x)

n = 200

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
x = np.sort(rng.random(n)*4 - 2)
source_data = func(x) + rng.normal(scale=1.5, size=n)
weights = np.ones_like(source_data)
weights[1:-1] /= 100  # adjust this value to enforce the endpoints more strongly
smoothing_spline  = make_smoothing_spline(x, source_data, w=weights)
smooth_data = smoothing_spline(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, source_data, ".")
ax.plot(x, smooth_data)

print(source_data[[0,-1]] - smooth_data[[0,-1]])  # [0.03957741 0.02589737]
```

[image]

You can also decrease the smoothing through the use of the `lam` argument (larger means smoother and smaller means less smooth). I'm not sure what scale this should generally be, but here is what I get when setting it to `lam=5e-6` (the absolute errors are: `[0.00874048 -0.00479941]`).

[image]

Comment: sounds like a good option. i can't verify right now because the version of scipy i'm locked at (1.7.3, python 3.7) doesn't have  `make_smoothing_spline`. But i will investigate

Comment: For some reason, the scipy documentation website won't let me change the version so I cannot see which interpolation methods were available in that version.